# Why do colours merged onto a shapefile in base R display incorrectly?

Tags: shapefile, r, merge, color

I have a shapefile:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/x1p9ctssdp6xz4r/AADZzy10j8VPigtWkcNxAZata?dl=0

which I read in like this:

```
Somalia = readOGR(dsn = "Somalia",
                  layer = "Somalia")
```

I then add a 'Count' column onto it so that each polygon is numbered:

```
Somalia$Count = 1:nrow(Somalia@data)

plot(Somalia)

text(gCentroid(Somalia, byid = TRUE), 
     labels = Somalia$Count, cex = 0.5)
```

[image]

I then create a colour palette I would like to use:

```
a = colorRampPalette(c("#EBF5FB", "#2a6d76"))
a(74)
plot(rep(1,74), col = a(74), pch = 15, cex = 3)
```

which looks like this:

[image]

I make it into a data frame:

```
b = a(74)
b = as.data.frame(b)
b[,2] = 1:74
colnames(b) = c("colour", "Count")
```

I check the class of the colour column as follows:

```
class(b$colour)
```

which returns: "factor"

I then merge the data frame onto the shapefile:

```
Somalia = merge(Somalia, b, by = "Count", all.x = TRUE)
```

and check the class of the colour column:

```
class(Somalia$colour)
```

which also returns: "factor"

However, when I then plot the shapefile:

```
plot(Somalia, col = Somalia$colour)
```

The colours are represented like this:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is and if there is a way around it?

Comment: Hard to tell without your data and your precise code of your workflow. How are you plotting? Are you accidentally making factors and so plotting by the numbers behind the factors?

Comment: As I suspected, your colours are factors, and so plot as if they were numbers. Use `plot(Somalia, col = as.character(Somalia$colour))` or convert the column to character and it works fine. If this gets reopened I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected, your colours are factors, and so plot as if they were numbers. Use plot(Somalia, col = as.character(Somalia$colour)) or convert the column to character and it works fine.